# Jest test axios error returned from a Promise. I get an "array"

Tags: javascript, axios, jestjs

I have this test:

```js
await waitFor(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toMatchObject([{
                type: "TRY_INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS",
            },
            {
                type: "INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS_FAILED",
                error: "Error: Request failed with status code 401"
            }]);
        });
```

But I get in console:

```sh
expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1

      Array [
        Object {
          "type": "TRY_INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS",
        },
        Object {
    -     "error": "Error: Request failed with status code 401",
    +     "error": [Error: Request failed with status code 401],
          "type": "INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS_FAILED",
        },
      ]
```

The difference is the "array" notation that really I receive.

In effect this is my action under test:

```js
return this.getApi()
                .index(id)
                .then(data => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: `INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS_SUCCEEDED`,
                        data
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: `INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS_FAILED`,
                        error,
                    });
                })
```

And I get error from:

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return response;
    },
    error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

I don't want to change error returned with `error.toString()` (it can works with error.toString(), I just tested it before), I want return from my Axios the error and solve that test.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `toMatchObject`, you can do this.

```
expect(store.getActions()).toMatchObject([
  {
    type: 'TRY_INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS',
  },
  {
    type: 'INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS_FAILED',
    error: { message: 'Request failed with status code 401' },
  },
]);
```

Or

```
expect(store.getActions()).toMatchObject([
  {
    type: 'TRY_INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS',
  },
  {
    type: 'INDEX_ROLES_ITEMS_FAILED',
    error: expect.objectContaining({
      message: 'Request failed with status code 401',
    }),
  },
]);
```

Comment: It works, and it is perfect!

If I would use a more strict "toContain", is it possible?

Comment: I accepted, It solved... By the way my doubt was replace `expect(store.getActions()).toMatchObject([` with `expect(store.getActions()).toContain([`

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tocontainitem

Comment: toContain uses strict equal

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if that is what you are asking for, but have you tried just using the error.message?

`return Promise.reject(error.message);`

Comment: I don't want to change error returned with error.toString() (it works with error.toString()), I want return from my Axions the error and solve that test.